# Android Studio OpenCV Canny detection failed T_T

Tags: android, opencv

I use Android Studio 2.3 version

and I use Opencv 3.2 for Android and android verison of my Phone is 4.4.2

this is some of my source codes.

please attention to case VIEW_MODE_CANNY

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    final int viewMode = mViewMode;
    switch(viewMode){
        case VIEW_MODE_RGBA:
            mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
            break;
        case VIEW_MODE_GRAY:
            Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.gray(), mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
            break;
        case VIEW_MODE_CANNY:
            try{
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
                Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mGray, mGray, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2);
                Imgproc.Canny(mGray, mIntermediateMat, 35, 75);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA, 4);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.i(TAG,e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
    return mRgba;
}
```

my application show 3 deferent view. Gray , Color and Canny

Gray and Color are run well.

but if I choose canny It is terminated automatically.

No log and No exception

I can not even guess why not

please give me tips..

Comment: You should try debugging your aplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me the error is in this line:

```
 Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
```

Should be:

```
 Imgproc.cvtColor(inputFrame.rgba(), mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
```

It crashes because you give an uninitialized input image to cvtColor.

By the way, your VIEW_MODE is a little bit confusing: it's not clear if it refers to the kind of input you get, or the kind of output you want to generate.